# How to make the input element in jquery append appear when the page reloads or refreshes

Tags: jquery, html

I tried to make an input form, where the input element will appear after the Add button is clicked. but sometimes when I input I often forget to press the refresh button and all my input is lost and have to start from the beginning again, how can the input element not be lost if it reloads or refreshes?

```
<button type="button" onclick="itemAdd()" >Add</button>
<div id="entry"></div>

<script>
var line= 1;
function itemAdd()
{
    var parts = '<input type="text" name="description"><input type="text" name="amount"><input type="text" name="price">';
    $('#entry').append(parts);  
    line++;

}
</script>
```

Comment: There is no HTML input holds data even you reload the page. The one and only way is store the data temporarily using `cookies` or `local-Storage`.

Comment: The best thing to do is to have a Save method that gets called as soon as you add a data input and save/fill it. Save method might call an API to send the added data to save it to a database or a file or whatever data persisting mechanism you want to use on the server.

Comment: Thanks @BanujanBalendrakumar, yes I thought it was wrong I tried to search but the reference still uses local-Storage.

Comment: @Yatin, thanks I've thought about using the API by sending temporary data to the database, but I haven't created the method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to persist added rows somewhere. Options are backend, localStorage, cookies etc. Here is a localStorage demo.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="itemAdd()">Add</button>
<button type="button" onclick="removeItem()">Delete</button>
<div id="entry"></div>

<script>
var parts = '<div><input type="text" name="description"><input type="text" name="amount"><input type="text" name="price"></div>';
var line = localStorage.getItem("lineCount") || 1;
for (var i = 0; i < line; i++) {
  $('#entry').append(parts);
}
function itemAdd()
{
  $('#entry').append(parts);
  localStorage.setItem("lineCount", ++line);
}
function removeItem()
{
  $('#entry').children().last().remove();
  localStorage.setItem("lineCount", $('#entry').children().length);
}

</script>
```

Comment: thanks @kasperite,nice it's work but how if wont to delete that element of variable parts??

Comment: did you test it in real browser?this script won't run in jsfiddle or any online code snippet editor due to missing localStorage. Save it into an html file and open it in browser

Comment: I tried running the script after I cleaned the browser cache and it went perfectly, but how do I delete one of the input rows?

Comment: Updated my answer, I updated the markup abit to make it easier for demoing